# Command to "re-probe" USB bus (M1 Mac)

Tags: usb, mac-mini

I am using a Dell U2722DE monitor with my M1 MacMini. The monitor uses a single USB-C cable for the display and the hub USB ports on the monitor, which include an 10BaseT connection. The display also supplies power over the USB-C cable to the computer, which is not useful for a MacMini and is intended for something like a MacBook (or it's windows equivalent).

When I reboot my MacMini, the display portion of the USB-C signal is fine, but I loose all of my USB ports, including the ethernet port. If I power-cycle the display (using the power button, not by removing the AC cord), I get the ethernet port back, but not the USB hub ports.

If I physically disconnect and reconnect the USB cable, everything is perfect...until the next reboot.

Is there a software command I can issue to have the USB controller "re-probe" all of the USB busses (or even a single bus). Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks. Kent

Comment: I have a similar problem, but with the USB hub on my Dell P2721Q. Kent, have you been abkle to fix this?

Comment: Firmware update on monitor fixed it. Not in release notes, but now it works without issue.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the response! I've got it to work by disconnecting the USB-C cable, turn off the monitor for a few seconds, reconnect and turn on monitor. This usually got it to work.... I'll also look into getting the monitor Firmware updated................